# Getting rewrite to work with SSL in a MVC Zend Framework app

Tags: zend-framework, ssl, url-rewriting

I am following the Zend Framework quickstart document and got stuck on the .htaccess rewrite rules. I am using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This works find when I access through HTTP, however, nothing is served when accessing through HTTPS. I am using a single directory for HTTP and HTTPS content.

I would not want to force HTTPS either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone out there has a same problem, and posted a blog on how to solve this, please take a look at it.

http://www.myscienceisbetter.info/fix-zend-framework-404-routes-on-https.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Zend Framework with HTTPS, and those rewrite rules work just fine.  It sounds like you're experiencing a configuration issue with the web server that has nothing to do with the rewrite rules.